# Android admin/root privilege without voiding warranty?

Tags: root-access, unrooting

is it possible to enable root without voiding warranty, at least for temporarily so power users can change hidden settings, access to root files for backup or customisation purposes etc and then disable root when needed? I think that would be great to have root/unroot option builtin on android like enabling/disabling developer options. Otherwise it takes extra time to root/unroot a device with 3rd party tools and has risks of bricking device, voiding warranty etc?

Having root/unroot option would be really good for many power users and developers out there. Cheers

Comment: because rooting device has risks of bricking (besides other risks) warranty has to be void. either you are power user and take the responsibility yourself, then you can root your device. or you want manufacturer take care about healthy and safe device and keep warranty. you can't have both

Comment: The only way to gain temporary root permissions is using an root exploit if your device is vulnerable. Unfortunately this means that every app could make use of that exploit without your consent, too.